# Send data to nodejs process

Tags: node.js

I want to have a nodejs app running and receiving different events (A)
Basically, I want to send data from another nodejs app to A and A to catch it and console.log it

But I do not want to use process.fork, I don't want to run other apps from inside A. I just want them to send data to process A.

I've been searching google a lot but no luck. I found something like echo xxx > /proc/7417/fd/0 to send data to the stdin but I want to send jsons.

Any ideas how to acomplish this ?

Comment: Do you intend to communicate between two nodejs apps?

Comment: How about using cluster module?

Comment: two or more. all other nodejs app to send data to A

Comment: what about server/client or peer-to-peer

Comment: why not send data as json?

Comment: what do you mean server/client or peer-to-peer. 
as jsons i want to send data.. I was thinking to open a express server and sending data with http.post .. I thought it was something else I could do

Answer (score 0):

Without having to go into low level programming with 'net' module, you can use [socket.io library](http://socket.io/) to easily implement cross process communication that you need. Check out their website and join slack group to get help once you got throw the starting bits of it.

In a nutshell:
You will probably want one process to be a master (which is the easiest network architecture to implement imo) which will run the communication hub, then use socket.io-client to establish connections to it from other processes and start exchanging data in whichever form you need.

The socket.io api is extremely easy to get so I am sure you will have no problem with it, their docs could sometimes seem a little scarce and some 'under-the-hood' quirks which are useful to know are not discussed there that's why I am suggesting you join their slack group and just ask when you bump into a problem.

Cheers

EDIT:
On a second thought:

- Use [redis pub-sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)
- And looking at jas- answer reminded me of of [node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) module which is made exactly for this purposes.

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are speaking of IPC methods such those traditionally used with signals programming. Events are a handy way of working with signaling a running service and implementing an API to do so.

Here are some resources;
Node.js documentation for events: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Events: http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/